# If $\mathbf{R}$ is an upper triangular matrix, then does $\|\mathbf{R}\| \le \|\mathbf{R} + \mathbf{R}^T\|$ hold?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathbf{R}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be upper triangular and $\|\cdot\|$ be the induced 2-norm of matrices.
Then, does $\|\mathbf{R}\| \le \|\mathbf{R} + \mathbf{R}^T\|$ hold?

Comment: False for $n = 3$ and $\mathbf R = \begin{pmatrix} 4 & 0 & 0 \\ 32 & 5 & 0 \\ 24 & -24 & 9 \end{pmatrix}^T$.

Comment: On the other hand, it looks like it's true for $n = 2$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thanks. I was trying to disprove it when $n = 2$ but couldn't.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Regarding which matrix norm?

Comment: @Sudix: The induced $2$-norm, i.e., the largest singular value.